# UWP make a collection of bitmaps to a video

Tags: c#, uwp, media

I picked some jpg images and add these images to the MediaComposition(composition).

It works. I got the count of clips.

```
private async void encodeImages_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    foreach (string extension in FileExtensions.Image)
    {
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(extension);
    }
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

    composition = new MediaComposition();
    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
    {
        m_files.Add(file);
        var clip =await MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync(file, TimeSpan.Zero);
        composition.Clips.Add(clip);
    }

    Debug.WriteLine(composition.Clips.Count);
}
```

Then I want to use MediaComposition generate a MediaStreamSource.

```
private  void showVideo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GC.Collect();

    //FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
    //savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
    //savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("MP4 File", new List<string>() { ".mp4" });
    //savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "output";
    //StorageFile videoFile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
    //await composition.RenderToFileAsync(videoFile);

    encodeImagesResult.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
    IMediaSource mediaStreamSource = composition.GeneratePreviewMediaStreamSource(400, 400);
    encodeImagesResult.SetMediaStreamSource(mediaStreamSource);
}
```

It will show the error "The parameter is incorrect."

What's wrong with my code? Many thanks!

Comment: //var composition = new MediaComposition();
composition is  a global  variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `The parameter is incorrect.` here means the parameter in [MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn652610) is incorrect. In this method, the second parameter `originalDuration` represent how long to display the image in the video clip. And for a video clip, its duration can't be zero.

So to fix this error, you can edit this line:

```
var clip =await MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync(file, TimeSpan.Zero);
```

and set the `TimeSpan` to the value that you want the image to be displayed for like:

```
var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync(file, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

After this, your code should be able to work.